# "Ask and you shall recieve" Can we ask for anything?

Tags: exegesis, prayer, gospels

I bet I've got it wrong but does "ask and thou shalt recieve" mean we can ask for anything and recieve anything? In which case, could I have a 'wish-list' of things I want glorified in heaven?

Like I said, I just KNOW I'm missing the point here. Having said which, surely it doesn't mean ask but make sure it's for something within this selection, otherwise why make the point at all? Being it was said by Jesus I'm guessing there was, not only a point, but a rather important one!!!

Comment: Again you question needs to be narrowed, there are very mixed opinions involved here. There are some people who belong to the name it and claim it theory and there are also people who believe that your request must be based on the precept that it only has to do with maintaining a relationship with God, and still others believe that it has to be based strictly on needs and not wants.

Comment: That answers my question...should have put it down as an answer and I'd have chosen it.

Comment: @ Thomas Jennings Thanks for the vote of confidence, but my reason for the comment was that since we are both new to the site it was my desire to help you to learn how this site seems to want questions asked as much as I can. Apparently we both require some education in that area. Us newbies have to stick together.

Comment: It would help if you could reference a specific passage for this question.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot ask for *anything* and expect to receive it. You can only expect God to give you what you pray for if what you ask for is consistent with His will.

See [1 John 5:14-15](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20John%205:14-15&version=NIV)

> 14 This is the confidence we have in approaching God: that if we ask
>   anything according to his will, he hears us. 15 And if we know that he
>   hears us—whatever we ask—we know that we have what we asked of him.

**Don't expect God to give you what you ask for if what you ask for is not in His will.**

From [Matthew Henry's Concise Commentary](http://biblehub.com/1_john/5-15.htm) (Emphasis mine)

> 5:13-17 Upon all this evidence, it is but right that we believe on the
>   name of the Son of God. Believers have eternal life in the covenant of
>   the gospel. Then let us thankfully receive the record of Scripture.
>   Always abounding in the work of the Lord, knowing that our labour is
>   not in vain in the Lord. The Lord Christ invites us to come to him in
>   all circumstances, with our supplications and requests,
>   notwithstanding the sin that besets us. ***Our prayers must always be
>   offered in submission to the will of God.*** In some things they are
>   speedily answered; in others they are granted in the best manner,
>   though not as requested. We ought to pray for others, as well as for
>   ourselves. There are sins that war against spiritual life in the soul,
>   and the life above. We cannot pray that the sins of the impenitent and
>   unbelieving should, while they are such, be forgiven them; or that
>   mercy, which supposes the forgiveness of sins, should be granted to
>   them, while they wilfully continue such. But we may pray for their
>   repentance, for their being enriched with faith in Christ, and
>   thereupon for all other saving mercies. We should pray for others, as
>   well as for ourselves, beseeching the Lord to pardon and recover the
>   fallen, as well as to relieve the tempted and afflicted. And let us be
>   truly thankful that no sin, of which any one truly repents, is unto
>   death.

Comment: Mk 14:36. And he said, "Abba, Father, all things are possible to thee; remove this cup from me; yet not what I will, but what thou wilt." Even Jesus didn't get what he asked for.

Answer (score 1):

What Jesus means is that you will not go without what you need. Take a look at [**Matthew 6:25-32**](http://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwt/E/2013/40/6#h=64:0-65:61) I'm primarily focusing on versus 31 & 32.

> *"So never be anxious and say, ‘What are we to eat?’ or, ‘What are we to drink?’ or, ‘What are we to wear?’ 32 For all these are the things the nations are eagerly pursuing. Your heavenly Father knows that you need all these things."*

You can pray for all sorts of things like strength, wisdom, discernment or good judgement, patience, his holy spirit.

Here is a way of illustrating the situation. Imagine God is your friend. This friend would do anything to make sure you did well. Your friend has the means to do anything or buy anything. What happens when you start using that friendship to gain money and valuable things?

What you ask for shows your motive.  If you ask for things that help you keep Gods commandments then he will indeed bless you. If you ask for thing out of desire for personal gain selfishly then God will ignore your prayer.

Look at the example of Jesus. He owned nothing, but the clothing he wore. Another guiding scripture is yet another verse from Matthew **6:19-21**:

> *“Stop storing up for yourselves treasures on the earth, where moth and rust consume and where thieves break in and steal. 20  Rather, store up for yourselves treasures in heaven, where neither moth nor rust consumes, and where thieves do not break in and steal. 21  For where your treasure is, there your heart will be also."*

Comment: @ Jeremy Matthew chapter 6:25 through 32 are claimed by both the name it and claim it camp and the it only pertains to the what you need camp as justification for their beliefs.